# C++ Private member Can not accesses memory at 0x0

Tags: c++

```
class List
{
    public:
List(void);     // constructor
~List(void);        // destructor

// Insert a fire into the list, maintaining the list in
// alphabetical order by name.
void add(const Fire& fire);

// Return a const pointer to the fire instance it finds in
// the list, or nullptr if it didn't find a fire with that name.
Fire* const find(const char * const name) const;


// Remove the fire with the specified name. Returns true if it
// found and removed the fire, false if it did not find the fire.
bool remove(const char* const name);

// Return how many fires are currently in the list.
int getLength(void) const;

// Print the contents of the list.
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const List& list);

private:

struct Node
{
    Node(const Fire& fire);         // constructor
    Fire fire;                      // an actual instance of Fire,
                                    // NOT a pointer to an instance
    Node *next;                     // next node in the linked list
};

Node    *first;
int     length;
};
```

This is my list.h file and

```
List::List(void) 
{
length = 0;
first = NULL;
}

List::Node::Node(const Fire& fire)
{
this->fire = fire;
this->next = NULL;
}


void List::add(const Fire& fire)
{
const char *str1;
const char *str2;
Node *newnode = NULL, *curr = NULL, *prev = NULL;

newnode = new Node(fire);
newnode->next = NULL;
if (first == NULL) {
    first = newnode;
    length++;
}
else {
    curr = first;
    str1 = curr->fire.getName();
    str2 = newnode->fire.getName();
    while (curr && strcmp(str1, str2) < 0)
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        if (curr)
        {
            str1 = curr->fire.getName();
        }
    }
    //insert in between
    if (prev)
    {
        newnode->next = curr;
        prev->next = newnode;
    }
    //insert at the beginning
    else
    {
        newnode->next = curr;
        first = newnode;
    }
}
length++;


}
```

These are part of my list.cpp file.
When I run it and try to add data to list, there're error about the `first(node)` and `length(int)` the gdb gives me these.

```
1: first = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>
2: length= <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x4>
```

Also cause Segmentation fault at

```
if (first == NULL)
```

Did I do something wrong within the constructor?
because it works last time when I coded. I know my code is messy, sorry.

add some of my code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if (argc > 1)               // turn off cout
    std::cout.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);


fires = new Database();

insertFire(Fire::District::Tillamook, "Strawberry Lane Fire", 45, 35, 212, 123, 57, 7);
insertFire(Fire::District::Tillamook, "Bob Straub", 45, 11, 463, 123, 57, 580);
insertFire(Fire::District::Astoria, "Mosquito Fire", 46, 9, 215, 123, 57, 573);
} // part of main

static void insertFire(Fire::District district, char* name,
                   int latDeg, int latMin, int latSec,
                   int longDeg, int longMin, int longSec)
{
Fire    *f;
char    *nm{new char[strlen(name) + 1]};

strcpy(nm, name);
f = new Fire(district, nm, latDeg, latMin, latSec, longDeg, longMin, longSec);
fires->insert(*f);
delete[] nm;
delete f;
}
```

and database.h and .cpp

```
class Database
{
public:
Database(void);             // constructor
virtual ~Database(void);    // destructor

// Insert a fire into the database.
void insert(const Fire& fire);


Fire* const find(const char* const name) const;

bool remove(const char * const name);

// Print the contents of the database.
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Database& database);

private:
List    *lists;
};
```

database.cpp

```
void Database::insert(const Fire& fire)
{
    lists->add(fire);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using this code?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that's using the `List` class.  My guess would be that you're invoking `List::add` through a `null` pointer.

Comment: Are you initializing `lists` in the constructor of `Database`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many small things that are not correct with this C++ code. Lots of C style code (initialization of variables at the beginning of a block, it's even not mandatory in modern C, but it's bad practice in C++).

- Variable initialization:

  List::List()
  :first(nullptr), length(nullptr)
  {
  }
- usage of "deprecated" `NULL` instead of `nullptr`
- `getName` should return a `const std::string`, not a const char* (or a `string_view`)

Then for the actual issue.

```
Node* newnode = new Node(fire);

if (first == nullptr) {
    first = newnode;
    ++length;
}
else
{
    while (curr && curr->fire.getName() < newNode->fire.getName())
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    //insert in between
    if (prev)
    {
        newnode->next = curr;
        prev->next = newnode;
    }
    //insert at the beginning
    else
    {
        newnode->next = curr;
        first = newnode;
    }
}
++length;
}
```

This is actually correct, and you never have a direct access to `first` and mainly `length`. There is only a `length` on `List`, meaning that you are invoking this method through a `nullptr`, which is an undefined behavior in C++.

First advice: read Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice using C++.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :D it's really helpful

Comment: *usage of "deprecated" NULL instead of nullptr* why is that bad? perhaps best to explain in the answer.

Comment: `NULL` is a macro defined to an integer (so not a pointer). `nullptr` is a typed null pointer.